# Как правильно обновить более 100000 записей в базе данных?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть json файл, из которого я считываю данные Code и Employees. Есть и базы данных, в которых есть те же столбцы. Мне нужно обновить базу, заменить Employees из файла по Code.

```
while ($reader->read()) {
   $employees_no = $crm_conn->query("
          UPDATE accounts_cstm 
             INNER JOIN accounts ON accounts_cstm.id_c = accounts.id 
             SET accounts_cstm.Employees = '{$Employees}' 
             WHERE accounts.Code = '{$Code}'");
}
```

Записей получается 100000+, и такой цикл длится оооочень долго. Возможно ли быстрее?

**EDIT**

По совету в комментариях сделал временную таблицу, и пробую обьеденить данные одним запросом. Все равно получается долго. Может надо как то лучше переписать запрос?

```
UPDATE accounts_cstm 
INNER JOIN accounts ON accounts_cstm.id_c = accounts.id 
INNER JOIN temp_employees ON (accounts.sic_code = temp_employees.sic_code)
SET accounts_cstm.employees_no_c=temp_employees.employees
WHERE accounts.sic_code = temp_employees.sic_code
```

**EDIT**

Я создал index key для sic_code в обеих таблицах в которых оно находится.

Теперь 100000 записей обновляется за несколько секунд! Может кто нибудь может в кратце обьяснить сие чудо? В гугл очень сложные обяснения нахожу...

Comment: Как минимум `autocommit = false` и prepared statements увеличат скорость. А дальше нужно смотреть на структуру таблиц и данных

Comment: сохраняете Code и Employees из json в csv, загружаете одной командой во временную таблицу, join'ите ее по code - одним запросом обновляете

Comment: Надо смотреть структуру. В добавок к вышесказанному перед обновлением, возможно, стоит стартануть транзакцию, прибить ключи с полем `accounts_cstm.Employees`, внести изменения, создать ключи повторно, завершить транзакцию

Comment: @splash58 может вы могли бы еще мне помочь? Я поредактировал вопрос.

Comment: Читайте по строчно, а не грузите весь файл целиком и потом гоняйте. Также, читайте про смещение по файлу.

Comment: индексы то есть на полях, которые соединяете? зы: зачем вам where, которое дублирует условие джойна?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону курсоров. PHP не рассчитан на долгую работу.
Можете в какую-то промежуточную таблицу записывать необходимые данные и в фоновом режиме производить обновление основной таблицы.

Comment: делайте left join  и во where проверяйте на не нуль

Comment: Я создал index key для sic_code в обеих таблицах в которых оно находится. 

Теперь 100000 записей обновляется за несколько секунд! Может кто нибудь может в кратце обьяснить сие чудо? В гугл очень сложные обяснения нахожу...

Comment: вам  главу в книге проще найти пролистав ее целиком или просмотрев оглавление? с индексом вкратце то же самое.

Comment: @teran о классный ответ. после того что прочитал смысл понял. :) А как этот индекс работает? когда я его устанавливаю на поля. в базе создается что то?

Comment: а это уже литературу/документацию надо читать, если хотите разобраться )