# Как оптимизировать mySql запросы через PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, парсер

Идет огромный поток информации, и это уже сейчас занимает много времени. Надо реализовать постепенную запись в БД. Как можно оптимизировать запросы? + надо еще перед записью проверять, существует ли уже запись с таким полем. Времени займет невероятно много, и это плохо

Comment: индексы, надеюсь, на колонки ставите?

Comment: @ArchDemon что имеете ввиду?

Comment: https://ruhighload.com/Индексы+в+mysql

Comment: Перед записью точно проверять не стоит, во первых это медленно, во вторых может возникнуть ситуация, что между тем как проверили и как вставили кто то другой вставил то же самое. Проверять надо одновременно с записью, т.е. использовать insert ignore или on duplicate key update. На вопрос в текущей редакции ответом может быть только книга, объемом 3000 страниц минимум. Надо рассматривать весь код, структуру БД, индексы, разбираться какие именно операции сколько времени отнимают и почему (буквально построчно)

Comment: "надо еще перед записью проверять, существует ли уже запись с таким полем" - использовать триггер (если внутри запроса обрабатывается сложная логика, то использовать процедуры). [первый комент может быть будет полезен](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1050967/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-100000-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85). Оптимизация через `php` наврядли возможна)